# Sencha Touch 2.3 and Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch 2.3 and Extjs 4.2
Issue: Handle multiple root nodes JSON response(from single response) in multiple stores. 
    
   `{
    total: 
    [
        {
            exp_amount_tot: "71962.00",
            income_amount_tot: "462129.00"
        }
    ],
    data: 
    [
        {
            id: "1",
            userid: "2",
            name: "Any",
            notes: "",
        },
     ]
    }`

I need to save the above response into two different stores. 
1. dataStore rootproperty:"data"
2. summaryStore rootProperty: "total"

Please help me to fix this issue.

Store:

```
proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            api: {
                create: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/create",
                read: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/getall",
                update: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/update",
            },
            reader: {
                type: "json",
            successProperty: 'success',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 different stores with "data" & "total" root properties respectively and use the store.add() method to add the data to individual store.

Comment: my current store like  proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            api: {
                create: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/create",
                read: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/getall",
                update: "http://localhost/api/getAccounts.php/update",
            },
            reader: {
                type: "json",
            successProperty: 'success',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
            },
        },